# Loopback 4 - Creating database tables for built-in models?

Tags: database-migration, loopbackjs, built-in, loopback4

For LB3 there is [specific documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html#creating-database-tables-for-built-in-models) on how create database tables for built-in models, but for LB4 it seems missing, the closest thing I could find is [this page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-models-core.html#migrating-models-persisted-in-a-database) in the migration guide, but it just explain the difference in models persistence handling and the advantages on having the repositories handling it instead of the models themselves.

Moreover, already having a mysql-based datasource, trying to create a repository to handle Users persistence result in error since it seems not to find the User built-in model.

[image]

How can I create table for built-int models, e.g. User, in LB4?

#### Update #1

Found [this page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial-sqldb.html#database-migration-using-npm-run-migrate-command) in the documentation that tells how to list models to migrate and to use `npm run migrate` so I've tryied to put `User` in the list but got the foolowing error: so it seems to find/recognize the model but complains about it not having datasource settings in the `model()` decorator (I guess).

```
root@71827bda8df9:/home/node/app# npm run migrate

> backend@0.0.1 premigrate
> npm run build


> backend@0.0.1 build
> lb-tsc


> backend@0.0.1 migrate
> node ./dist/migrate

Migrating schemas (alter existing schema)
Cannot migrate database schema Error: Cannot migrate models not attached to this datasource: User
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:1146:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Long story short

Cannot create tables for built-in models.

##### Why?

Found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206313/loopback-4-extend-the-built-in-user-model?rq=1) with a similar problem, and the accepted answer links to [this docs page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Understanding-the-differences.html#conceptfeature-mapping) where built-in models are still marked as TBD almost 4 years later.

##### So what now?

I guess I have to create my own user model and integrate it with what LB4 offers me to handle users authentication.